# neo4j - Get all connections where a condition is matched

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get all the nodes where a particular condition matches. The CSV looks,

```
DIAGNOSIS          DRUG_NAME        TOTAL_COST  AVERAGE_COST
ARTHRITIS           RIMADYL           38.87     38.87
EAR INFECTION       RIMADYL           15.67     7.835
MASSINMAMMARYGLAND  RIMADYL           32.49     16.245
```

So when I give the following command,

```
MATCH (d:DIAGNOSIS)-[r:medicine]->(dn:DRUG_NAME)-[r1:costs]->(tc:TOTAL_COST)-[r2:avg_costs]->(ac:AVERAGE_COST)
WHERE d.id = 'ARTHRITIS'
RETURN distinct dn,r, d,r1,tc,r2,ac
```

I am getting the below graph.

[image: Result]

However what I want to get is one connection i.e., row 1 from my CSV.

Comment: I'm guessing your model is off. You have one drug with 3 different total and average costs, and no way to associate the costs with the diagnosis. Some things to consider, maybe have your total and average costs on the relationship between the :DIAGNOSIS and :DRUG_NAME nodes, or maybe have an intermediate node between :DRUG_NAME and :DIAGNOSIS to hold the cost data for the drug for that diagnosis.

Comment: You can also use CREATE instead of MERGE when loading your CSV so it creates 3 RIMADYL nodes instead of one, But agreed with the above - the design of your graph (nodes + relationships) does not seem to fit what you expect out of the graph.